# What regex would achieve this requirement?

Tags: regex, unix, grep

What would be the regex to achieve this (can't seem to quite get it):

Notes:

- Note that the number in square brackets might change form run to run.
- Will be used in Mac terminal as part of a "grep" (i.e. grep'ing output on a log file in real time)

INPUT:

```
Jul 19 07:32:19 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b5df900   10  nil began
Jul 19 07:32:19 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b5df900   10  nil ended/cancelled
Jul 19 07:32:19 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b544ff0   10  nil began
Jul 19 07:32:20 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b544ff0   10  nil ended/cancelled
Jul 19 07:34:00 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b549270   10  nil began
Jul 19 07:34:00 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b549270   10  nil ended/cancelled
Jul 19 07:34:02 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b33ab50   10  nil began
Jul 19 07:34:02 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b33ab50   10  nil ended/cancelled
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT

```
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b5df900 10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b5df900 10  nil ended/cancelled
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b544ff0 10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b544ff0 10  nil ended/cancelled
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b549270 10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b549270 10  nil ended/cancelled
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b33ab50 10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b33ab50 10  nil ended/cancelled
```

Comment: So you want everything from `<Warning>` to the end of the string?

Comment: well moreso evertying after the final "]" after "CoronaView" really, as the text after this may change (may be an Error not Warning for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mac following `awk` should do the job:

```
awk -F'CoronaViewer\[[0-9]+\] *' '/CoronaViewer\[[0-9]+\]/{print $2}' file
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b5df900   10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b5df900   10  nil ended/cancelled
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b544ff0   10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b544ff0   10  nil ended/cancelled
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b549270   10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b549270   10  nil ended/cancelled
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b33ab50   10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b33ab50   10  nil ended/cancelled
```

**Alternative:** If you can install `gnu-grep` using `home brew` on OSX (like I have) then this `grep -P` will do the same thing:

```
grep -oP "CoronaViewer\[\d+\] \K<Warning>:.*" file
```

Comment: Sorry also clarified in the OP:  well moreso evertying after the final "]" after "CoronaView" really, as the text after this may change (may be an Error not Warning for example)

Comment: thats really close anubhava - it's working except that non-matching lines seem to come through as blank lines (instead of nothing coming through) - does that make sense to you?

Comment: Check updated code now. Non matching lines won't be printed now.

Comment: +1 for awk-fu, and I really like the `grep -oP` on top. I know it's an OSX question, but in case anyone is interested the equivalent on Win would be `pcregrep`

Answer (score 2):

### Edit

On Mac, you could use the following:

```
perl -nle 'print $1 if /\] *(.*)/' file
```

If it has to be after 'CoronaViewer' ...

```
perl -nle 'print $1 if /CoronaViewer\[[0-9]+\] *(.*)/' file
```

Comment: I seem to get a usage error when running this on the Mac.  I used:  cat main.lua | grep -Po '^.*\K<Warning.*'

Comment: sorry - also clarified in the OP:  well moreso evertying after the final "]" after "CoronaView" really, as the text after this may change (may be an Error not Warning for example)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer using `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^<]*\(<.*\)/\1/' filename
```

If you know for a fact that the data you need always starts at column 43 (as in your example), you can use `cut` as

```
cut -c43- filename
```

Comment: thanks - didn't seem to work/return anything in my usage:  idevicesyslog | grep 's/[^<]*\(<.*\)/\1/'

Comment: No, you should use `sed` instead of `grep`.  It should work then.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oP "(?<=^\w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} iPhone CoronaViewer\[\d{4}\] ).*$"
```

DEMO:

```
# c.txt contains:
Jul 19 07:32:19 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b5df900   10  nil began
Jul 19 07:32:19 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b5df900   10  nil ended/cancelled
Jul 19 07:32:19 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b544ff0   10  nil began
Jul 19 07:32:20 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b544ff0   10  nil ended/cancelled
Jul 19 07:34:00 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b549270   10  nil began
Jul 19 07:34:00 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b549270   10  nil ended/cancelled
Jul 19 07:34:02 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b33ab50   10  nil began
Jul 19 07:34:02 iPhone CoronaViewer[4043] <Warning>: userdata: 0x1b33ab50   10  nil ended/cancelled

> grep -oP "(?<=^\w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} iPhone CoronaViewer\[\d{4}\] ).*$" c.txt
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b5df900   10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b5df900   10  nil ended/cancelled
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b544ff0   10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b544ff0   10  nil ended/cancelled
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b549270   10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b549270   10  nil ended/cancelled
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b33ab50   10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b33ab50   10  nil ended/cancelled
```

As usual, the correct regex for things like this tend to be what you want to EXCLUDE rather than what you want to INCLUDE, so that's a crucial part of this.

Comment: Hi Adam, I get this when running on the mac.  usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: @Greg I don't have a mac to test with, so I don't know why that would be, sorry. As far as I'm aware, that should work on any machine that supports `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '{sub(/.*\] /,"")}1' file
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b5df900   10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b5df900   10  nil ended/cancelled
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b544ff0   10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b544ff0   10  nil ended/cancelled
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b549270   10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b549270   10  nil ended/cancelled
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b33ab50   10  nil began
<Warning>: userdata: 0x1b33ab50   10  nil ended/cancelled
```

---

Or if you like to make sure its only line with `CoronaViewer` that should be printed:

```
awk '/CoronaViewer/ {sub(/.*\] /,"");print}' file
```